# Scalar found where operator expected

Tags: perl

I don't think this is a duplicate 'cause I've been looking to all other subjects with the same title. So, here's my code:

```
while ($n>0)
{
   if (($n%10)%2 eq 0)
   $k = $k+1;
   $n = $n/10;
}
```

I made a program that would calculate how many even numbers are in the number n
and when I try to run my program, this error is shown:

```
Scalar found where operator expected at script.pl line 7, near ")
        $k"
        (Missing operator before $k?)
syntax error at script.pl line 7, near ")
        $k "
```

Line 7 would be that:

```
$k = $k+1;
```

Comment: Probably unrelated, but that `eq` should be `==` for comparing non-string values

Answer (score 3):

See `perldoc perlsyn`:

> ```
> if (EXPR) BLOCK
> if (EXPR) BLOCK else BLOCK
> if (EXPR) BLOCK elsif (EXPR) BLOCK ...
> if (EXPR) BLOCK elsif (EXPR) BLOCK ... else BLOCK
> ```

… an `if` statement must be followed by a **block**, not an expression.

```
if (($n%10)%2 eq 0) {
    $k = $k+1;
}
$n = $n/10;
```

You could also use `if` as a statement modifier:

> ```
> Any simple statement may optionally be followed by a SINGLE modifier, just
> before the terminating semicolon (or block ending). The possible modifiers
> are:
>
>     if EXPR
> ```

… in which case your code would look like:

```
$k = $k+1 if ($n%10)%2 eq 0;
$n = $n/10;
```

… but [this usage is discouraged](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl-Critic/lib/Perl/Critic/Policy/ControlStructures/ProhibitPostfixControls.pm).

---

Aside: Compare numbers with `==` not `eq`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you have previous experience in a programming language where block markers are optional if an `if` block contains only a single statement. In Perl they are always required.

```
if (($n%10)%2 == 0) {
    $k = $k+1;
}
$n = $n/10;
```

I've also changed `eq` to `==` - as it looks like you are comparing numbers, not strings.

Answer (score 1):

You're using Perl to write Python code. It's much better for Perl code!

```
while ($n>0)
{
   if (($n%10)%2 eq 0)
   $k = $k+1;
   $n = $n/10;
}
```

You got the braces right for the `while`; the `if` needs the same treatment, like this

```
while ( $n > 0 ) {

    if ( ( $n % 10 ) % 2 eq 0 ) {

        $k = $k + 1;
        $n = $n / 10;
    }
}
```

But Perl has many more operators than Python, so I would write this, noting that `( $n % 10 ) % 2` is identical to `$n % 2` because 2 is a factor of 10, and you should be using `==` instead of `eq` for numeric equality

```
while ( $n ) {

    next if $n % 2;

    ++$k;
    $n /= 10;
}
```

And I think you should force `$n` to be an integer in both languages